# Scraping this type of site architecture possible?

Tags: web-scraping, xmlhttprequest, httprequest, httpresponse

I'm trying to build a web application for a customer. It implements a simple remote search on this site:

https://www.handelsregister.de/rp_web/mask.do?Typ=n

All I need to do is insert some value in the input field labeled `Company or keywords`, perform the search and get the HTTP response.

The problem is I am not familiar with this kind of architecture; I have always worked with APIs that have URLs, etc. Is it possible to perform the above operation automatically by programming?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably. You could send POST requests and parse the response. Here is a basic example in Python with the module `requests` :

```
import requests 

query = "test"

post_fields = {'suchTyp':'n',
        'registerArt':'',
        'registerNummer':'',
        'registergericht':'',
        'schlagwoerter':query,
        'schlagwortOptionen':2,
        'ergebnisseProSeite':100,
        'btnSuche':'Rechercher'}

response = requests.post("https://www.handelsregister.de/rp_web/search.do", data=post_fields)
print(response.status_code)
print(response.text)
```

Comment: wow, thank you so far. Does this really works and gives the html response? Have you test it?

Comment: @AlexanderDeBeur Of course, I do not post any script without having tested it. But this is just the beginning. It will simply return you the HTML code of the first page of results. You will then need to parse this HTML to get a formatted table.

Comment: sure, many thanks again. I have some experience with parsing html due to other (nasty) projects, so now I know that at least its possible.